# Symfony - Pass variable to form ->add to the getter

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to pass a variable to the getter in the entity from the form->add('field', 'collection', ....)

entity.php

```
public function getFilteredFields($var) {
    //......Do stuff
}
```

formtype.php

```
->add('filteredFields', 'collection', array(
            'type'          => new FieldTextType(),
)
```

Comment: What is the goal behind doing so?

Comment: I am trying to filter the collection so it only returns the selected group from the collection instead of all of the records in that collection.

Comment: Aham, I believe that it is not possible. Alternatively, you could fetch `1:N` with applied filter and then submit the data to form...

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to filter the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via [events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#pre-populating-the-form-formevents-pre-set-data-and-formevents-post-set-data).

Create subscriber/eventListener for `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` and manually populate valid data. You could register subscriber as service and inject needed dependencies.

example form building:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
            \Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                /* @var $form \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
                $data = $event->getData();
                /* @var $data myEntity */
                $filteredFields = $data->getFilteredFields();
                // get data for $somePopulatedValue
                $form->add(
                    'filteredFields',
                    'collection',
                    [
                       'options' => ['choices' => '...'],

                    ]
                );
            }
        );
```